# Sourcing data format from multiple different structures

Tags: python, design-patterns, scrapy

### Problem

I want to read in the data to dictionary

```
person = {
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'email': 'johndoe@email.com',
    'age': 50,
    'connected': False
}
```

The data comes from different formats:

**Format A.**

```
dict_a = {
    'name': {
        'first_name': 'John',
        'last_name': 'Doe'
    },
    'workEmail': 'johndoe@email.com',
    'age': 50,
    'connected': False
}
```

**Format B.**

```
dict_b = {
    'fullName': 'John Doe',
    'workEmail': 'johndoe@email.com',
    'age': 50,
    'connected': False
}
```

There will be additional sources added in the future with additional structures.

### Background

For this specific case, I'm building a Scrapy spider that scrapes the data from different APIs and web pages. Scrapy's recommended way would be to use their `Item` or `ItemLoader`, but it's ruled out in my case.

There could be potentially 5-10 different structures from which the data will be read from.

### Implementation

#### `/database/models.py`

```
"""
Database mapping declarations for SQLAlchemy
"""

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean
from database.connection import Base

class PersonModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    connected = Column(Boolean)
```

#### `/mappers/person.py`

```
"""
Data mappers for Person
"""

# Abstract class for mapper
class Mapper(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

# Data mapper for format A, maps the fields from dict_a to Person
class MapperA(Mapper):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.name = ' '.join(data.get('name', {}).get(key) for key in ('first_name', 'last_name'))
        self.email = data.get('workEmail')
        self.age = data.get('age')
        self.connected = data.get('connected')

    @classmethod
    def is_mapper_for(cls, data):
        needed = {'name', 'workEmail'}
        return needed.issubset(set(data))

# Data mapper for format B, maps the fields from dict_b to Person
class MapperB(Mapper):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.name = data.get('fullName')
        self.email = data.get('workEmail')
        self.age = data.get('age')
        self.connected = data.get('connected')

    @classmethod
    def is_mapper_for(cls, data):
        needed = {'fullName', 'workEmail'}
        return needed.issubset(set(data))

# Creates a Person instance base on the input data mapping
def Person(data):
    for cls in Mapper.__subclasses__():
        if cls.is_mapper_for(data):
            return cls(data)
    raise NotImplementedError


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from database.connection import make_session
    from database.models import PersonModel

    # Sample data for example
    dict_a = {
        'name': {
            'first_name': 'John',
            'last_name': 'Doe'
        },
        'workEmail': 'johndoe@email.com',
        'age': 50,
        'connected': False
    }
    dict_b = {
        'fullName': 'John Doe',
        'workEmail': 'johndoe@email.com',
        'age': 50,
        'connected': False
    }

    # Instantiate Person from data
    persons = [PersonModel(**Person(data).__dict__ for data in (dict_a, dict_b)]
    with make_session() as session:
        session.add_all(persons)
        session.commit()
```

### Question

I have limited experience in Python programming and I'm building my first scraper application for a data engineering project that needs to scale to storing hundreds of thousands of Persons from tens of different structures. I was wondering if:

1. This is a good solution? What could be the drawbacks and problems down the line?
2. Currently I've implemented different subclasses for the mapping. Is there a convention or industry standard for these types of situations?

*Update*

- For question 2, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456672/class-factory-in-python) question to be useful, but would still want to know if this approach in general is good.
- Added style improvement suggestions from @Reinderien

Comment: I'm happy that you're taking my feedback into account, but it's against site policy for you to edit your question's code as suggestions come in. A new question should be issued with the revised code. Before that, I'm going to edit my answer with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't abuse inner lists

This:

```
self.name = ' '.join([data.get('name').get(key) for key in ['first_name', 'last_name']])
```

should be

```
self.name = ' '.join(data.get('name', {}}.get(key) for key in ('first_name', 'last_name'))
```

Note the following:

- Generators don't need to go in a list if they're just being passed to a function (`join`) that needs an iterable
- Give an empty dictionary as the default for the first get so that the second get doesn't explode
- Use a tuple instead of the last list because the data are immutable

### Use set logic

This:

```
return all(key in data for key in ('name', 'workEmail'))
```

is effectively asking "are both 'name' and 'workEmail' in `data`?" There's a better way to ask this - with a `set`.

```
needed = {'name', 'workEmail'}
return needed.issubset(set(data))
```

If `data` can be stored as a `set` once outside of this function, it will increase efficiency.

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

### Don't needlessly materialize generators

This:

```
# Instantiate Person from data
persons = [Person(data) for data in [dict_a, dict_b]]

# Store persons that fit the database model
persons = [PersonModel(**person.__dict__) for person in persons]
```

makes a generator, saves it to a list in memory, consumes that list, makes a second generator, and stores that generator in a second list in memory. Instead:

```
persons = [PersonModel(**Person(data).__dict__)
           for data in (dict_a, dict_b)]
```

Again, the last inner list should be a tuple.

### Parsing heuristics

It's not useful to write separate parsing classes for formats A and B in this case, because they aren't declared by the API so have no meaning. Write a translation routine for every member you extract from the JSON. Do a series of attempts against known paths in the data to get the members out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Makes sense as well. However, my core question is more on a higher level: is this kind of approach optimal for this challenge or perhaps there is a better or easier way to solve this kind of data mapping from sources.

Comment: @maivel How do you detect which format the data will follow? Do you know by filename, or does the user specify, or do you need to autodetect it?

Comment: I would need to autodetect it. The API that provides me the `.json` which I will convert to `dict` is prone to changing their response layouts and naming conventions.

Comment: @maivel refer to edited answer.